# Python - how to convert ctime to '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any direct way to convert ctime value to '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' format?

For example, convert "Wed Nov  6 15:43:54 2013" to "11/06/2013 15:43:54"

I tried the following but does not give me the format I want, which is "11/06/2013 15:43:54":

```
>>> t = time.ctime()
>>> f = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
>>> print f
2013-11-06 15:43:54
```

But if I pass it directly to time.strftime, it'll want 9-item sequence:

```
>>> n = time.strftime(t, '%D %H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you could just use `datetime.now`:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[7]: '11/06/2013 18:59:38'
```

But.  If you're taking in a `ctime` style string from somewhere else, parse it with `datetime.strptime` then format it in the way you want using datetime's `strftime` (not `time`'s).

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
d = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[9]: '11/06/2013 19:01:11'
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to format the string with the specifier you want

```
import time
import datetime
t = time.ctime()
f = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print f                               #with no specifier
print f.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') #with your specifier
```